# String encoding question

Tags: javascript, string

What is the encoding of this string?

```
\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20
```

P.S. I found it in some Javascript source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is Hexadecimal for "Hello "

- 'H' is 48
- 'e' is 65
- 'l' is 6C
- 'o' is 6F

20 is a space

Here is a list of ascii codes: http://www.asciitable.com/

The `\x` is just telling something that it is hexadecimal. In a Javascript string it will `\x48` will represent a single character ('H'). `x` is commonly used to mean hex.

For example, since 48 is Hexadecimal for the decimal number 72, the javascript statement:

`0x48 === 72` is true

You can convert from Hex to ascii in javascript with `String.fromCharCode(0x48)`.

You can convert from hexadecimal to decimal with `parseInt('0x48')`

Answer (score 1):

Each of the values of the form `\xNN` are hexadecimal literal values.  They map to ASCII values encoding particular characters.  If you go to a JavaScript console (for example, the one in the Chrome browser I'm using now) and enter

```
alert("\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20");
```

You'll get a popup that says

```
Hello
```

Since the ASCII values for the letters H, e, l, and o are 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, and 0x6F, respectively.  The final 0x20 encodes a space character, which does not display anywhere.

For more information about the ASCII table for encoding character values, see [this website](http://www.asciitable.com/) containing the complete table.

My question is why on earth any site would do this.  It's less space-efficient in terms of number of source characters than just writing out `Hello`!

Answer (score 1):

That's [hexadecimal](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html) for the string `Hello`.